# reportlab line spacing and fitting of a Paragraph in a table

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportlab 3.1.44 in python 2.7
Here is the code that is using a paragraph in a table.

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.colors import Color

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()


def make_report():
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("hello.pdf")
    story = []
    style = styles["Normal"]
    ps = ParagraphStyle('title', fontSize=20)

    p1 = "here is some paragraph to see in large font"
    data = []
    table_row = [Paragraph(p1, ps),\
                 Paragraph(p1, ps)\
                ]


    data.append(table_row)
    t1 = Table(data)
    t1.setStyle(TableStyle([\
               ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.red, None, (2,2,1)),\
             ]))
    story.append(t1)

    doc.build(story)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_report()
```

The are 2 problems when the font is large.

- the text is larger that the cell so it goes beyond the borders
- the spacing between the lines is too small

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 2 problems are actually caused by the same issue, namely be the height of the `Paragraph`. The table cell is determined by the linespacing which determines the height of a line. And at the same time the lack of whitespace it also caused by the linespacing.

In Reportlab the linespacing is set using the `leading` style attribute according to the docs.

> Interline spacing (Leading)
>
> The vertical offset between the point at which one line starts and where the next starts is called the leading offset.

Thus the correct version of your code would use:

```
ps = ParagraphStyle('title', fontSize=20, leading=24)
```

Which result in:
[image: Example of the output after correction]

Comment: Great. Works well. Thanks.